# AngularJS RequireJS loading angular-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, sails.js

I am having a hard time with loading the [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) module to my application. I've been reading all sort of tutorial, example, questionc, etc. Can you guys help me figuring out what I am doing wrong here?

I get the following error message : `Failed to instantiate module angular-file-upload`

Here is my code

**mymodule/module.js**

```
define(['angular', 'angular.file.upload'], function (angular) {
'use strict';
    return angular.module('app.mymodule', ['angularFileUpload']);
});
```

**mymodule/index.js**

```
define([
'./routes',
'./models/index',
'./controllers/index',
'./directives/index'
], function () {});
```

**app.js**

```
define([
    'angular', 
    'angular.resource', 
    'angular.ui.bootstrap', 
    'angular.ui.router', 
    './relation/index', 
    './controllers/index', 
    './directives/index', 
    'config'
], function (angular) {
    'use strict';    
    return angular.module('app', [
        'ngResource',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ui.router',
        'app.relation',
        'app.controllers',
        'app.directives',
        'app.constants'
    ]);
});
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'angular': '../lib/angular/angular',
        'angular.route': '../lib/angular-route/angular-route',
        'angular.resource': '../lib/angular-resource/angular-resource',
        'angular.ui.bootstrap': '../lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls',
        'angular.ui.router': '../lib/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router',
        'angular.file.upload': '../lib/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload',
        ...
    },

    shim: {
        'angular': {'exports': 'angular'},  
        'angular.resource': ['angular'],
        'angular.ui.bootstrap': ['angular'],
        'angular.ui.router': ['angular'],
        'sails.io' : ['socket.io']
    }
});

require([
  'angular',
  'app',
  'config',
  'routes'
], function(angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.element().ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/blob/master/dist/angular-file-upload.js) for `angular-file-upload` you can see that it does not register itself as an AMD module, meaning that we have to provide a shim that makes sure that all of its dependencies are loaded before we load `angular-file-upload` itself.

The main dependency is of course `angular` - so we need to setup a shim to make sure that `angular` is loaded before `angular-file-upload`. In your case, I guess the requirejs config should look something like this:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "angular"             : "relative/path/to/angular",
        "angular.file.upload" : "relative/path/to/angular-file-upload",
        ... other modules
    },
    shim: {
        "angular": {
            exports: "angular"
        },
        "angular.file.upload": ["angular"]
    }
})
```

Then you should be ready to rock.

Comment: I was also stuck with a similar issue where 'angular is undefined' was thrown. I changed the shim for angular to exports and it worked. Can you explain what this does, and why just "angular.file.upload": ["angular"] wont work?
"angular": {
            exports: "angular"
        }

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same library I use you probably want to inject `angularFileUpload` and not `angular-file-upload`.

Comment: You may not have helped @Frank6, but you helped me. Thanks!

Comment: I would love to know how it was helpfull ?